# Non-existent 301 redirect

Tags: server, redirect, http-redirect

I had a new domain name set up and I keep getting 301 redirects from this site... Even though its folder is empty (no .htaccess either).

I cleared my history with all the checkboxes possible on Chrome for "Since the beginning of time", went in chrome://net-internals to clear my DNS and flush the sockets and I rebooted the computer... However I am still getting this 301 redirect.

*EDIT* I also tried to add a .htaccess file to redirect to the correct website, no luck.

When I see the detail of the cache I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2015 22:01:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Location: http://www.badwebsite.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=172800
Expires: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 22:01:22 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I asked a few colleagues and they did not have this redirect, so the problem is probably on my end and I would like to know if someone has any idea about how to fix this ?

Comment: Perhaps it's set up in the central server configuration? Have you tried from another machine?

Comment: Ok so after a good night of sleep and another cache clear, everything seems to be working fine... Weird.